# Laravel using where clause on a withCount method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do a where clause on withCount method of laravel's eloquent query builder using this piece of code.

```
$posts = Post::withCount('upvotes')->where('upvotes_count', '>', 5)->get();
```

and this code is giving me this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'upvotes_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *, (select count(*) from `upvotes` where `upvotes`.`upvoteable_id` = `posts`.`id` and `upvotes`.`upvoteable_type` = App\Post) as `upvotes_count` from `posts` where `upvotes_count` > 5)

So from what I can guess is that upvotes_count isn't selected and hence the column is not being found, BUT if I execute this piece of code.

```
$posts = Post::withCount('upvotes')->get();
```

Then I am getting this output.

```
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": 15,
"title": "Voluptatum voluptas sint delectus unde amet quis.",
"created_at": "2016-10-07 13:47:48",
"updated_at": "2016-10-07 13:47:48",
"upvotes_count": 7
},
{
"id": 2,
"user_id": 2,
"title": "Molestiae in labore qui atque.",
"created_at": "2016-10-07 13:47:48",
"updated_at": "2016-10-07 13:47:48",
"upvotes_count": 2
},
```

Which basically means that upvotes_count is being selected, hence i am really confused about how to solve this problem.

(More options that I tried so far are given below with the respective error associated to it.)

```
$posts = Post::where('id', $id)->withCount(['upvotes' => function($query) {
        $query->where('upvotes_count', '>', 5);
    }])->get();
```

error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'upvotes_count' not supported (forward reference in item list) (SQL: select *, (select count(*) from `upvotes` where `upvotes`.`upvoteable_id` = `posts`.`id` and `upvotes`.`upvoteable_type` = App\Post and `upvotes_count` > 5) as `upvotes_count` from `posts` where `id` = 1)

code.

```
$posts = Post::where('id', $id)->with(['upvotes' => function($query) {
        $query->select('upvoteable_id AS upvotes_count');
    }])->where('upvotes_count', '>', 5)->get();
```

AND

```
$posts = \App\Post::where('id', $id)->with(['upvotes' => function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('upvoteable_id AS upvotes_count');
    }])->where('upvotes_count', '>', 5)->get();
```

error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'upvotes_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `id` = 1 and `upvotes_count` > 5)

---

I just want to use where clause on a count() method which is in a relationship with a parent model.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can achieve requested result by using:

```
$posts = Post::withCount('upvotes')
         ->having('upvotes_count', '>', 5)
         ->get();
```

Comment: I am still getting the error: column `upvotes_count` does not exist.  I am not sure how this works since from my research it looks like the having clauses are executed before the select statements, therefore the alias `upvotes_count` is not yet defined. I am using Postgres. Does this only work for MySQL?  Is there a way around this other than having to do a `havingRaw` to manually get the count again?

Comment: @Stetzon `withCount('upvotes')` should add `upvotes_count`, so you should add this, or if you still have this problem, send me the query and i will check it.

Comment: @Stetzon Remember that you cannot do where clauses on aggregated columns, You can however do having clauses, so make sure that you are not doing where there.

Comment: I also have an error that the column doesn't exist with MySQL.

Comment: Same here, "Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "users_count" does not exist". The thing is, "having()" is producing the error, "orderBy" works.

Answer (score 34):

another good way to do this
we can filter that separately and even assign an alias to that column name

```
$posts = Post::withCount([
    'upvotes', 
    'upvotes as upvotes_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('upvotes_count', '>', 5);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Now in blade you can do

```
$posts->upvotes_count
```

Comment: Thank you for this example with a custom query, and a count alias. That allows us to add multiple counts on the same related table, but with different custom queries.

Comment: Happy it helped.

Comment: actually this is the right way for relation

Comment: Isn't `'upvotes as upvotes_count'` enough, do we really need to have `'upvotes'`, in array passed to `withCount(...)`method?

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this was implemented after your question, but you can now do it like this

```
$posts = Post::has('upvotes','>',5)->get();
```

Answer (score 7):

I think using has() is the best solution:

```
Post::has('upvotes','>',5)->withCount('upvotes')->get()
```

You could also use a filter:

```
Post::withCount('upvotes')->get()->filter(function($post) { return $post->upvotes_count > 5; })
```

You could also disable strict mode in config/database.php (probably not a good idea)

```
'strict' => false,

Post::withCount('upvotes')->having('upvotes_count','>',5)->get()
```

You could also try to add a groupBy clause (using having in strict mode), but this will likely require you to include every column in your table (due to 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'), which could break things if you ever add another column to your table, and probably won't work anyway because I think you need to include 'upvotes_count' in the groupBy and it seems to be a non grouping field.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. It allows a condition thanks to the has() function and the withCount allowed me to use an orderBy. Again, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to select only rows that the counter is greater than or equal to 1 you can try the following code:

```
$posts = Post::withCount('upvotes')
             ->havingRaw('upvotes_count')
             ->get();
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but it's an alternative. Another alternative would be get the posts and use array filter as mentioned in a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and tried the same things you did.  I'm guessing there is a way to replicate the SQL generated by the withCounts call but add a way to make xxx_counts available to a where clause, but I just filtered the resulting collection instead.

```
$allTags = Tag::withCount('articles')->get();

$usedTags = $allTags->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value->articles_count > 0;
    });
```

Comment: It's been quite a time, and as I learnt more about sql, you can't do where clauses on the aggregate functions, hence upvotes_count column isn't found since it's aggregated and not selected. 

but the above problem can be solved using some advanced queries and grouping them together.