# Laravel 5.6 withCount and where statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel 5.6.

I have 3 tables : players, games and game_player table.

Retrieving the game count of every player is easy with this in the index action of the PlayersController:

```
//Get game count of every player
$players = Player::withCount('games')->get();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the game count for the games when the player has won the game? (in the index action of the playerscontroller) I'm not sure how to do this. Can someone help?

**games table migration**

```
$table->integer('winner')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('winner')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');
```

[image]

**game_player table migration**

```
table->integer('game_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('player_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');
```

[image]

**game model relation**

```
public function players(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player')->withTimestamps();
}

//this is for the winner of the game
public function player()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Player');
}
```

**player model relation**

```
public function games(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game')->withTimestamps();
}

//the game the player has won
public function game()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Game');
}
```

**playerscontroller**

```
public function index()
{
    $players = Player::all();

    //Get game count of every player
    $players = Player::withCount('games')->get();

    /*Load the view and pass the groups*/
    return \View::make('players.index')->with('players', $players);
}
```

The result I want is to get played games (is working) and won games.

[image: result]

**player > index blade**

```
@foreach($players as $player)
   <p>{{ $player->id }}</p>
   <p>{{ $player->firstname }} {{ $player->lastname }}</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Played games: {{ $player->games_count }}</li>
      <li>Won games: </li>
   </ul>
@endforeach
```

**update**

I don't think we can see it as a duplicate of this question ([Laravel using where clause on a withCount method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930975/laravel-using-where-clause-on-a-withcount-method)) because I'm using a many to many relationship also.

If I use this code which isn't the correct one, because the 1 needs to be dynamic $id:

```
$players = Player::withCount('games')
     ->having('winner', '=', 1)
     ->get();
```

I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'winner' in 'having clause' (SQL: select `players`.*, (select count(*) from `games` inner join `game_player` on `games`.`id` = `game_player`.`game_id` where `players`.`id` = `game_player`.`player_id`) as `games_count` from `players` having `winner` = 1)

**update 2**

When I use this code:

**controller**

```
$players = Player::all();

//Get game count of every player
$players = Player::withCount('games')->get();

$wongames = Player::withCount(['games' => function($query) { $query->where('winner', '=', 5); }])->get();

//$players = Player::withCount('games')->where('winner', '=', 1);

/*Load the view and pass the groups*/
return \View::make('players.index')->with('players', $players)->with('wongames', $wongames);
```

**blade index**

```
@foreach($players as $player)
   <p>{{ $player->id }}</p>
   <p>{{ $player->firstname }} {{ $player->lastname }}</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Played games: {{ $player->games_count }}</li>
         @foreach($wongames as $wongame)
            <li>Won games: {{ $wongame->games_count }}</li>
         @endforeach
   </ul>
@endforeach
```

I get this (not what I exactly want, but getting there I think):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel using where clause on a withCount method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930975/laravel-using-where-clause-on-a-withcount-method)

Comment: Try `Player::withCount(['games' => function($query) { $query->where('winner', '=', 1); }]`. The logic is the same of using `with()` with additional query constraints.

Comment: Player::withCount('games')->where('winner', '=', 1)->get();

Comment: @EliasSoares I just get a blanc page now ; @MikeFoxtech I get the error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'winner' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `players`.*, (select count(*) from `games` inner join `game_player` on `games`.`id` = `game_player`.`game_id` where `players`.`id` = `game_player`.`player_id`) as `games_count` from `players` where `winner` = 1)

Comment: My example code is short and don't include the `->get()` part. did you included it?

Comment: @EliasSoares This is what I used : $players = Player::withCount(['games' => function($query) { $query->where('winner', '=', 1); }]);

Comment: now I used ->get(); See my update 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you define a foreign key on the games table, you have a one-to-many relationship between the `Player` and `Game` already. Try adding the following relation to your `Player` model:

```
// Player.php
public function won()
{
    // must specify the foreign key because it is not the usual `_id` convention.
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'winner');
}
```

Then access it on each player like:

```
@foreach($players as $player)
    {{ $player->won->count() }}
@endforeach
```

Rather than querying in the view file, you should ideally do the following in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    /*Load the view and pass the groups*/
    return \View::make('players.index')->with('players', Player::with('won')->get());
}
```

Comment: This worked! Nice! Thanks @DigitalDrifter I just need to study this so I can also understand what you are doing. In the player model, you create a function where you get the games associated with your player_id. and in the view you use that function with a count?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Eloquent has naming conventions where it uses `_id` on the end of foreign keys by default. Since you named your foreign key `winner` instead of `winner_id` you need to tell the `hasMany` method what the foreign key name is. If it was `winner_id` you could just do `return $this->hasMany(Game::class);`

Comment: Okay :-) what is the "::class" for?

Comment: Do note however, that looping in the view is running queries how it's written. It's best to eager load the won games like I show in the controller method using `with`.

Comment: `::class` is the fully qualified name of the object, so `App\Models\Player`, for example.

Comment: With this return \View::make('players.index')->with('players', $players, Player::with('won')->get()); I also get the played games.