# List of categories of products with the respective quantity of products associated in Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to have a list of categories of products with the respective quantity of products associated to them (categories) in laravel 5 like this:

**electronics** (20) items,
**cell phones** (100) items

**expected JSON format:**

```
{
"name": "electronic",
"quantity": "20"
},
{
"name": "cell phones",
"quantity": "100"
},
```

Anyone have an idea how to implement this in laravel 5?

**EDIT**
Now my **controller** is like this:

```
    private $categories;

public function __construct(Categories $categories) {
    $this->categories = $categories;
}

public function index(){

    $categories = $this->categories
    ->withCount('products')
    ->get();

    $data = ['data' => $categories];
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

In mu **Model** i have:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Products')
    ->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as total')
    ->groupBy('category_id');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Categories');
}
```

it's now returning those error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.categories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `categories`.*, (select count(*) from `products` where `categories`.`id` = `products`.`categories_id`) as `products_count` from `categories`)"
```

in my database [image of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgMNR.png)

laravel is calling my column in plural and when i change the column name in database to **categories_id** it works fine, but i dont what to do that

Comment: Please provide some code. On what part are you stuck?

Comment: I've edited the post adding the code

Comment: I've solved my problem by specifying the foreign key **category_id** in the model, Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by specifying the the foreign key category_id in the model, the final code in the Categories model is:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Products', 'category_id')
    ->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as total')
    ->groupBy('category_id');
}
```

And it works fine

**the JSON response from POSTMAN is:**

```
        "id": 18,
        "category_name": "electronics",
        "description": null,
        "icon": "tv",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "products_count": 20
    }
```

If experiencing the same problem see [that link too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865193/laravel-5-6-withcount-and-where-statement)